# Symfony 5 :Key "DATE" for array with keys "NumberProjects, date" does not exist

Tags: sql, symfony, orm, symfony5

hi guys right now im working in small project and i feel like im stacked, so basically im trying to write a new query to select a specific data from my db, im trying to get projects that create at the same year and month.
this is my query and it work fine in MySql :

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS NumberProjects, DATE AS date FROM projects 
 GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM DATE),
          EXTRACT(month FROM DATE) ;
```

but when it comes to symfony this is will not work  of course  and i do not know whats the problem
this is my function

```
 /**
     * @return Projects[] Returns an array of Projects objects
     */
    public function findAllArchive():array
    {
        {
            $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(id) AS NumberProjects, DATE AS date FROM projects 
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM DATE),
                             EXTRACT(month FROM DATE) ';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }

    }
```

this is my twig

```
 <div class="sidebar-box ftco-animate">
            <h3>Archives</h3>
          <ul class="categories">
            {% for archive in archive %}
              {{ dump(archive.DATE) }}
              <li><a href="{{ path('blog_archive',{'date':archive.DATE|date("F Y")}) }}">{{ archive.DATE|date("F Y", "Europe/Paris") }}<span>{{ archive.total }}</span></a></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
```

update
i tryed with this one and i got this error : [Semantical Error] line 0, col 80 near 'EXTRACT(year': Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable

```
    public function findAllArchive():array
    {
        {
           $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('p');
           $qb->select('p.date AS DATE','COUNT(p.id) AS total')

                ->groupBy('EXTRACT(year FROM DATE)');

        }
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
any help pls !
```

Comment: Can you post your corresponding twig code?

Comment: @ jljohnstone of course but i don't think that the problem came from twig

Answer (score 0):

so i figure it out guys,the doctrine do not know EXTRACT function so i tried this and it work fine

```
public function findAllArchive():array
{
    {
        $entityManeger=$this->getEntityManager();
        $query=$entityManeger->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('YEAR(p.date) AS gbYear,MONTH(p.date) AS gbMonth, COUNT(p.id) AS total ')
            ->from('App:Projects','p')
            ->groupBy('gbYear')
            ->addGroupBy('gbMonth')
            ;


    }

    return $query->getQuery()->execute() ;

}
```